# How do I troubleshoot YARN compilation errors with React components?

Tags: reactjs, carbon-design-system

I'm starting to build my way on the world of React web apps, for that I'm following the Carbon Design System tutorial available here: https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/developing/react-tutorial/step-1

For when I start adding Routing based on the steps of the page, I found myself stuck in the following failed to compile error:

```
    Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js
TypeError: [BABEL] /home/hvg1928/carbon-tutorial/node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js: api.assumption is not a function (While processing: "/home/hvg1928/carbon-tutorial/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/dependencies.js$0$18")
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

As I understand, a call is being made to api.assumption in the React Refresh plugin which I don't see listed in the dependecies of the package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@carbon/icons-react": "10.22.0",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001258",
    "carbon-components": "10.25.0",
    "carbon-components-react": "7.25.0",
    "carbon-icons": "7.0.7",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.5",
    "react": "16.10.0",
    "react-dom": "16.10.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1"
  },
```

Based on this, where should I start looking for troubleshooting this compilation error? Are there a series of steps that could be used to troubleshoot compilation errors like these?

Comment: First thing I do when confronted with a compilation error is copy and paste it into a search engine: [`api.assumption is not a function`](https://www.bing.com/search?q=api.assumption+is+not+a+function) yields 66,400,000 Results... The top one was [a Babel issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/discussions/12949).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I did looked around but it seems that the search results Google gave me did not include that link, it looks really useful as it seems to point to the same issue I'm dealing with.